How to get cookie or set cookie in ajax request
I need to access to cookie cart_currency and get the value of that cookie. I write a JS frontend code:
$.ajax({
        url: product_url+'.json',
        
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
          
var cartCurrencyCookie = xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
var cartCurrencyValue = getCookieValue(cartCurrencyCookie, 'cart_currency');
console.log('cart_currency value:', cartCurrencyValue);

but it won't return me any value.
I also try to set in a page in the PHP code:
<?php

setcookie('cart_currency', 'USD', time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day
?>

but it won't affect the result from Ajax...
Is there any way to set cookie cart_currency='USD' or just take the cookie value in ajax response?
